# Cocos2dxActivity flicker

Tags: android, c++, android-activity, cocos2d-x

When i start a Cocos2dxActivity and show another activity (third party sdk activity or custom activity) for a period of time, the cocos2dxActivity starts flickering. When the other activity appears completed, the cocos2dxActivity returns to normal.

```
public class MyActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity {

    public static void showSDKLogin() {
        sdkMgr.showLogin();
    }
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("game");
    }
}
```

In `sdkMgr.showLogin()` function it start a new activity to show some dialog. i call it by jni in cocos2dx c++ code.

How do I solve the flickering problem?

ps: Sorry about my poor english. I wish you guys know what i mean ;)

Answer (score 3):

About the flickering on Android here is the solution - https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/5320

You should update the file "Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java" and after update the "onPause" and "onResume"

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    this.setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

    this.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.this.mCocos2dxRenderer.handleOnResume();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {

    this.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.this.mCocos2dxRenderer.handleOnPause();
        }
    });

    this.setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

    // super.onPause();
}
```

Cheers.